# The import org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService cannot be resolved

Tags: spring, microservices

Earlier I was using **spring-boot-starter-parent** version `1.5.7.RELEASE`, when I upgrade dependency to `2.0.4.RELEASE`, I am getting below error: The import

> org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService cannot be resolved

Also, Spring Data Mongo also has updates:

> The method findOne(Example) in the type QueryByExampleExecutor is not applicable for the arguments (String)
>
> The method delete(Person) in the type CrudRepository is not applicable for the arguments (String)

I am pretty sure that, `org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService` gets deprecated in Spring v2.0.x.RELEASE.

Any pointer whats the replacement of this class? Or can I tweak my logic now ?

**PersonCounterService.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class PersonCounterService {

    private final CounterService counterService;

    @Autowired
    public PersonCounterService(CounterService counterService) {
        this.counterService = counterService;
    }

    public void countNewPersons() {
        this.counterService.increment("services.person.add");
    }

    public void countDeletedPersons() {
        this.counterService.increment("services.person.deleted");
    }

}
```

**PersonController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository repository;
    @Autowired
    private PersonCounterService counterService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Person> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Person findById(@RequestParam("id") String id) {
        return repository.findOne(id);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Person add(@RequestBody Person p) {
        p = repository.save(p);
        counterService.countNewPersons();
        return p;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void delete(@RequestParam("id") String id) {
        repository.delete(id);
        counterService.countDeletedPersons();
    }

    @PutMapping
    public void update(@RequestBody Person p) {
        repository.save(p);
    }

    @GetMapping("/lastname/{lastName}")
    public List<Person> findByLastName(@RequestParam("lastName") String lastName) {
        return repository.findByLastName(lastName);
    }

    @GetMapping("/age/{age}")
    public List<Person> findByAgeGreaterThan(@RequestParam("age") int age) {
        return repository.findByAgeGreaterThan(age);
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
server:  
  port: ${port:2222}

spring:  
  application:
    name: first-service

logging:
  pattern:
    console: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
    file: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
#  level:
#    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
  file: app.log

management:
  security:
    enabled: false

---

spring:
  profiles: production
  application:
    name: first-service
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: 192.168.99.100
      port: 27017
      database: microservices
      username: micro 
      password: micro
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 4):

Micrometer is now integrated into spring boot 2.0. 
Read more here: [Micrometer-Springboot](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/16/micrometer-spring-boot-2-s-new-application-metrics-collector)

Tweak your logic by using MetricRegistry

```
@Bean
MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> addPersonRegistry() {
    return registry -> registry.config().namingConvention().name("services.person.add", Type.COUNTER);
}

@Bean
MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> deletePersonRegistry() {
    return registry -> registry.config().namingConvention().name("services.person.deleted", Type.COUNTER);
}


@Service
public class PersonCounterService {

    private final Counter personAddCounter;
    private final Counter personDeleteCounter;

    public PersonCounterService(MeterRegistry registry) {       
        this.personAddCounter = registry.counter("services.person.add");
        this.personDeleteCounter = registry.counter("services.person.deleted");
    }

    public void countNewPersons() {     
        this.personAddCounter.increment();
    }

    public void countDeletedPersons() {
        this.personDeleteCounter.increment();
    }

}
```

Finally, hit the actuator endpoint to view the metrics:

```
/actuator/metrics/services.person.add

{"name":"services.person.add","description":null,"baseUnit":null,"measurements":[{"statistic":"COUNT","value":1.0}],"availableTags":[]}
```